# How to link to my PayPal donate page from within a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, paypal, donations

Is there some simple donation URL I'm missing from PayPal?

When I generate my donate button, PayPal returns some HTML I can paste into my web page. Unfortunately this link generates some session keys and whatnot.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----Masdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfsadfasdfasdfasdfasdf=-----END PKCS7-----
">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Is there some simple URL I can place into my WPF application?

I'm placing an image of the donation picture:

[image]

And on the click of that picture:

```
    private void donation_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Process.Start("http://donation page here.com/");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong! Rest assured the cleanup monkeys have been sent!", "Woops!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
```

Where Process.Start will open the url in the users default web browser.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you generate your button, you should tick "Save button with PayPal" in Step 2 of the button creation tool. Then you should get two tabs in the results: **Website** containing the HTML button and **Email** containing a simple link that could be pasted into an email. You should be able to use the simple Email link in your application.

Comment: For anyone wondering this does work very well. Thank you for your help Matthew. :)

Comment: Note: This only works if donations are officially allowed in your country (just ask PayPal if they are), and you need a PayPal Premier or Business account for it to work. If you have a Personal account, no 'Email' tab will appear

Comment: Alternative link that always works: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donations&business=your-paypal-email-here&amount=leave-empty-or-set-donation-amount&item_name=set-donation-name-here-or-leave-empty

Comment: @Robert: That's not correct. I have a regular PayPal account that's linked to my Bank account and verified and I had the email tab display. As far as I know, I'm not Premier or Business in any way.

Comment: @Sergio: "a regular PayPal account" is a Premier account. It's just the account type; it doesn't mean you're paying an extra monthly fee for the account or anything. But I can assure you you'll have a Premier account if that option is available. Anyway, your issue is fixed. :-)